# Angular 2 CLI Project read json data from file

Tags: angular

I'm trying to read a json file from within my Angular2 src/app folder

The directory structure is as follows:-

[image]

And I'm trying to read the file in app.config.js using the following code:-

```
public load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.get("config.json")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.cache['config.json'] = new ConfigData(data.json());
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
}
```

But everything I try results in the following error:-

zone.js:2224 GET http://localhost:4200/config.json 404 (Not Found)

Where do I need to put the file?

I've tried moving it to the src directory to no avail. I've also tried:-

app/config.json
./app/config.json

I also added an assets folder under app and added it into there but that didn't work either

What do I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: You need to put external files in your assets folder.

Comment: I tried that but that also didn't work

Comment: Can you also add it to your question?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: But how did you try to reach it, I mean what did you write to the url in your http request?

Comment: same thing:- this._http.get("config.json"), also tried 'assets/config.json', './assets/config.json'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148335/discussion-between-bigbytes-and-echonax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the config.json file in assets folder and change the request to following,

```
public load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._http.get("assets/config.json")
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((data) => {
                this.cache['config.json'] = new ConfigData(data.json());
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
}
```

It should work. make sure to relunch the to make the changes reflect in www/assets folder.

Comment: Still gives the same error:- zone.js:2224 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/config.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: you have to add the config.json file inside src/assets folder and not inside src/app/assets folder as you have mensioned in the question

Comment: @BigBytes If this solved the problem, then please mark the answer as correct!